# Recover deleted files from MacBook Retina's SSD

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

I need to recover deleted files from my MacBook Retina. The files were deleted by an app update and didn't make it into the Trash.

Is it possible to recover files from an SSD? I have used programs in the past that worked on spinning platter hard drives and was wondering if there was anything similar I could use for an SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, most SSD firmware permanently wipes pages soon after they're marked as free by the OS sending a [Trim command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28computing%29), so unless you've only deleted it within the last couple seconds, you're [basically out of luck](http://www.howtogeek.com/187104/warning-anyone-can-recover-deleted-files-from-your-usb-drives-and-external-ssds/).